# Scala patternmatching: do nothing for some cases

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have to perform some actions based on cases in a pattern matching block, but only for selective cases, and nothing to be done for remaining. So is it ok to just return () for remaining cases? Something like this:

```
    val x = ....
    val y = ....
    (x, y) match {
              case (Some(number), Some(text)) => {
                ...... 
              }
              case (Some(number), None) => {
                ......
              }
              case (_, _) => () // do nothing
            }
```

Comment: In your code the `match` result isn't being saved. This indicates A) each `case` can return anything it wants, and B) a poor design that needs some re-thinking.

Comment: Not sure I agree with @jwvh about the poor design as we only see a small portion of your code. Anyway this code is perfectly valid. I assume that the other cases also return `Unit`?

Comment: It seems to me that in your case statements you perform some side effects. As said @gael we cannot infer much information about your code, so it is only a feeling :). But, if you perform really side effects, it could be better to wrap it in some IO Monad (like cats IO). Furthermore, more information about your intent can be precious to give you a more detailed answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally ok, if all the cases in a `match` result in `Unit` (spelled `()` in Scala), to have a case result in `()` to preserve exhaustivity.

That said, in this case, where you require the first `Option` to be defined to do anything, I would probably express this as:

```
x.foreach { number =>
  y match {
    case Some(text) =>
      ???  // note that { } aren't required in match and ??? is idiomatic for "some code here"

    case None =>
      ???
  }
}
```

Then again, I particularly dislike pattern matching on `Option`, so ymmv.

Comment: This results in a `NotImplementedError` exception being thrown when matching `None`. Dima's answer is the correct way to do nothing (`case _ => // then nothing else`).

Comment: That's because of the `???`: replace that with what you want to do in the `None` case, e.g. `()` for "do-nothing"

Answer (score 5):

Depends what you mean by "ok". If you are asking if it will compile, you can easily answer that question yourself, by running a few snippets in a REPL and find out, that you don't even need to return a unit. Something like this works just fine:

```
    "foo" match { 
        "bar" => "baz"
        "bat" => 1500
         _ => 
     }
```

If however by "ok" you meant whether it is a good idea, then the answer is "probably not". As mentioned in the comments, this is not type-safe and also purely side-effecting and not referentially transparent. There is likely a better way to do what you want.